# Centroid within non-convex 2d polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons, centroid

The centroid of an object is defined as the arithmetic mean of all points of the object. For non-convex objects, the centroid is often not a part of the object itself:

[image: Polygon with centroid outside the object]

Is there a definition of a centroid-like point which always lies within the object?

[image: Polygon with centroid within the object]

A definition that tackles 2 dimensional polygon objects is sufficient. I could think of something like the following, however, I would prefer a well-known definition if there is one:

1. Let $s_p(a, b)$ be the shortest path from $a \in p$ to $b \in p$ such that all points of the path are within $p$.
2. Let $S_p := \{s_p(a, b) | a, b \in p\}$.
3. Let $d$ be the longest path in $S_p$.
4. The mid point of $d$ is a centroid-like point and it always lies within $p$.

Comment: But which properties should such a point have? You cannot expect it to retain all properties of the centroid. For instance: how would you choose this centroid-like point in the case of an annulus?

Comment: The point should be some kind of central point that lies within the object. I dont know the exact properties because I am not that familiar with geometry. Are there any useful definitions of "special" points that always lie within the object?

Comment: In the case of an annulus, for instance, any point you choose inside the object will not respect its rotational symmetry. Would that be fine for you?

Comment: Yes, I think any point is fine in case of an annulus. However, if the annulus is sliced, I expect the point to be directly opposite to the slice. Maybe some mid point of some skeleton would do fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In geography there is an interesting point called *Pole of inaccessibility*: the most distant internal point from the polygon outline.

It is found by an iterative method, described in the *Methodology* section of [this](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B_xuyENh5ksFOGE1ZmU5ZjQtNjZmNi00ZTRlLWIyZGUtNmRiNDhhNzRkYTA1&export=download&hl=en) paper.

Links of interest:

https://sites.google.com/site/polesofinaccessibility/

https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel

Comment: This definition is short, easy to understand, and seems to fit my use case. Thank you :)